# Handling MongoDB's ISODate() when attempting to parse a serialized JSON string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, mongodb, knockout.js

I'm using MongoDB via the official C# driver with an ASP.NET MVC web site.

I have the following C# model:

```
public class Contact
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
}
```

Which, when pulled from MongoDB and serialized into a JSON string via MVC looks like:

```
{
    "_id"  : ObjectId("52eaad4839b60812fca4bf28"),
    "Name": "Joe Blow",
    "DateAdded" : ISODate("2014-01-30T19:51:35.977Z")
}
```

When I attempt to convert this from a JSON string to a Javascript object on the browser via JSON.parse(), I get the following error:

> `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token I`

This is because `ISODate(...)` is not valid JSON

`ObjectId()` is also not valid JSON, but the way I'm handling that is to simply perform a `string.replace()` on the JSON string prior to parsing it on the client. I considered doing the same for `ISODate()` but it feels a little too hacky.

Is there something I can do without resorting to regular expressions on the client side? Perhaps something from the MongoDB driver?

Comment: You have also problems with `ObjectId(...)` not only `ISODate`. This is not a valid json.

Comment: I remove`ObjectId()` from the string before parsing it, leaving behind the encapsulated GUID.

Comment: Then Do it the same for `ISODate`, Json.net, for ex, can handle the rest of it.

Comment: Could you add a global function called ISODate prior to parsing?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you need to tweak your JSON serializer a bit more. Try this:

```
var jsonWriterSettings = new JsonWriterSettings { OutputMode = JsonOutputMode.Strict };
Console.WriteLine(document.ToJson(jsonWriterSettings));
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I prefer that the generated JSON not need to be massaged on the client. Thanks!

Comment: It works to produce 'valid' JSON, but it produces some pretty bad values. Dates turn into { entered: { $date: 190012312211 } } which a typical application will have a hard time doing something useful with. A custom JSON.NET converter can fix that but still. Be really nice if JsonOutputMode. Strict could produce 'standard' Json.

Answer (score 11):

You SHOULD use `JsonConvert` to properly convert the Date to Json. the accepted answer produces a date object like: `{ $date: 190012312211 }` as @Rick Strahl mentioned. This should work:

```
object val = BsonTypeMapper.MapToDotNetValue(bsonDocument);
string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(val);
```

Comment: what if your bsonDocument is a list?

Answer (score 2):

If the JSON data is safe for eval (since its coming from your server it probably is) then you can do like so.  It's not particularly pretty, but it gets the job done.

http://jsfiddle.net/CVLhx/

```
var str = '{"_id"  : ObjectId("52eaad4839b60812fca4bf28"),"Name": "Joe Blow","DateAdded" : ISODate("2014-01-30T19:51:35.977Z")}';

function ObjectId(id) { return id;}
function ISODate(d) {return d;}

var obj = eval('(' + str + ')');
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: This works for JavaScript, the question is tagged with C# though.

Answer (score 2):

as @Louie Almeda suggests, i think the best approach is with the BsonTypeMapper.MapToDotNetValue. BsonTypeMapperOptions can be customized too.

Here's what i'm using to convert a list on BsonDocument to a json string using LINQ and newtonsoft serializer :

```
var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bsonDocuments.ConvertAll(d => BsonTypeMapper.MapToDotNetValue(d)), Formatting.Indented)
```

Answer (score 1):

I realize that I am very late to this party but I'll post an answer anyway in case somebody else comes along looking for a solution (as I did).

The trick is to let the Mongo db driver do the deserialization:

```
var collection = database.GetCollection<Contact>("collection name");
var contact = collection.Find(Query.EQ("Name", "Joe Blow"));
```

Now `contact` will have the expected values.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var IDict = v as IDictionary<string, object>;
                        var dict = IDict.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
                        var dateVal = dict["$date"];
                        var epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
                        var dateTimeVal = epoch.AddMilliseconds(Convert.ToDouble(dateVal));
```