# Is it possible to deserialize a "ISODate" field of MongoDB to a JToken (C#) ?

Tags: c#, json, mongodb, serialization, json.net

**Scope:**

I am writing a [set of tools](https://github.com/MarcelloLins/MongoTools/) to help people run common operations on their MongoDB databases, and "Exporting" data is one of them.

Currently I support full JSON export and "CSV", but the latter is way trickier.

The exporting tool allows for a "ConfigFile" which specifies which fields will be deserialized (from a [BsonDocument](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/core/document/)), not caring about their type. Most of types are currently working, but "ISO" Dates are still giving me headaches.

**Dynamic Deserialization**

Currently I am relying on [JObjects](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) to handle the Parsing of the "Json" documents, just like this :

```
        // Json Writer Settings - To avoid problems with 10Gen types
        var jsonSettings = new JsonWriterSettings () { OutputMode = JsonOutputMode.Strict };

        // Mapping string to a dynamic json object
        JObject mappedJson = JObject.Parse (jsonObject.ToJson (jsonSettings));
        
        // Trying to extract property values out of the object
        foreach (Field field in _configuration.Fields)
        {
                // Checking for JToken Type
                JTokenType objType = fieldData.Type;
                
                // Sanity Check for NULL Values of properties that do exist
                if (objType == JTokenType.Null)
                {
                    fieldValue = String.Empty;
                }
                else if (objType == JTokenType.Array) // Checking for Arrays (that need to be serialized differently)
                {
                    String[] valuesArray = fieldData.Select (t => t.Value<String> ().Replace (_configuration.ListDelimiter, String.Empty)
                                                                                    .Replace (_configuration.Delimiter, String.Empty)).ToArray ();

                    fieldValue = String.Join (_configuration.ListDelimiter, valuesArray);
                }
                else if (objType == JTokenType.Object && field.Name.Equals ("_id")) // Checking for specific MongoDB "_id" situation
                {
                    fieldValue = fieldData.ToObject<String> (); // Value<ObjectId> ().ToString ();
                }
                else
                {
                    // Reaching Attribute Value as "String" (if nothing else worked)
                    fieldValue = fieldData.Value<String> ();
                }
        }
```

**The Problem:**

This code works for all types I have tested so far, but "DateTime". The way MongoDB stores is as follows : `"PublicationDate" : ISODate("2014-08-10T00:00:00.000Z")`, which completely breaks my deserialization.

I have tried to deserialize it as "DateTime" and as "Object", but both of them fails to work. Is there any proper way of doing this ? This is basically all I am missing to make this "Dynamic Exporter" works.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Since your tools are controlling the JSON output, you should be able to export dates to JSON in a more standard format; see here for how to do so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21466446/handling-mongodbs-isodate-when-attempting-to-parse-a-serialized-json-string

Comment: The expression ISODate("2014-08-10T00:00:00.000Z") is not valid in Json. You can see the Json definition at http://www.json.org/. Json.Net supports some extensions, like comments, but dates are NOT in the Json definition. Do you have a complete example of the Json you want to parse with Json.NET?

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39331230/2282634

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`try catch` can be a solution in a bad way to catch iso datetime ? Like `JTokenType.Date`.

```
using System.Globalization;

public static void ParseMongoDBISODate()
{
    // Json Writer Settings - To avoid problems with 10Gen types
    var jsonSettings = new JsonWriterSettings() { OutputMode = JsonOutputMode.Strict };

    // Mapping string to a dynamic json object
    JObject mappedJson = JObject.Parse(jsonObject.ToJson(jsonSettings));

    // Trying to extract property values out of the object
    foreach (Field field in _configuration.Fields)
    {
        // Checking for JToken Type
        JTokenType objType = fieldData.Type;

        // Sanity Check for NULL Values of properties that do exist
        if (objType == JTokenType.Null)
        {
            fieldValue = String.Empty;
        }
        // Checking for Arrays (that need to be serialized differently)
        else if (objType == JTokenType.Array)
        {
            String[] valuesArray = fieldData.Select(t => t.Value<String>().Replace(_configuration.ListDelimiter, String.Empty).Replace(_configuration.Delimiter, String.Empty)).ToArray();

            fieldValue = String.Join(_configuration.ListDelimiter, valuesArray);
        }
        // Checking for specific MongoDB "_id" situation
        else if (objType == JTokenType.Object && field.Name.Equals("_id"))
        {
            fieldValue = fieldData.ToObject<String>(); // Value<ObjectId> ().ToString ();
        }
        else
        {
            try // it's a bad way but you can set fieldValue as a DateTime
            {
                //JTokenType.Date
                DateTime mongoDBISODate = DateTime.Parse(fieldData.Value<String>(), null, DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind);
                fieldValue = mongoDBISODate;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // Reaching Attribute Value as "String" (if nothing else worked)
                fieldValue = fieldData.Value<String>();
            }
        }
    }
}
```