# MongoDB C# driver and DateTime field

Tags: c#, mongodb, datetime-format

I'm inserting a document to MongoDB collection using C# driver, one of the fields types vs a DateTime when i debug the application i see the server time in the "FrameTimeStamp" fields i'm passing to Mongo, this is my code:

```
FrameDocument frameDoc = new FrameDocument();
frameDoc.Frame = imageBA;
frameDoc.EventCodeId = 1;
frameDoc.SesionId = 1;
frameDoc.FrameTimeStamp = DateTime.Now;
frameDoc.ServerUserId = (int)toMongoDt.Rows[0]["ServerUserId"];
frameDoc.TraderId = (int)toMongoDt.Rows[0]["TraderId"];
frameDoc.ActivePick = (int)toMongoDt.Rows[0]["ActivePick"];
frameDoc.TraderName = (string)toMongoDt.Rows[0]["TraderName"];
frameDoc.ServerUserName = (string)toMongoDt.Rows[0]["ServerUserName"];

var mongoCon = "mongodb://127.0.0.1";
MongoClient client = new MongoClient(mongoCon);
var db = client.GetDatabase("Video");

var frameCollection = db.GetCollection<FrameDocument>("Frame");
frameCollection.InsertOne(frameDoc);
```

in the shell when I'm reading the data i see it in the following format:
 **2016-08-14T06:10:33.295Z** and the time is not the server time, its UTC, how can i force mongo to write the DateTime as i pass it,?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

as per [CSHARP-185](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-185)

> MongoDB stores all DateTimes in UTC. Any local times you supply are
>   converted to UTC when stored in the database. The recommended approach
>   is to always convert DateTime values to UTC yourself before storing
>   them in the database, that way you are in full control. You can also
>   tell the C# driver that you want to work in LocalTime, like this:

```
[BsonDateTimeOptions(Kind = DateTimeKind.Local)]
public DateTime Date
{ get; set; }
```

Comment: Notably, DateTimes passed as query parameters are also converted from localtime to UTC at well.

Comment: I tried the mentioned approach, but MongoDb always stores the UTC format. After that I just convert the datetime as follows-    Convert.ToDateTime(dateOfBirth).ToLocalTime()                                                        
and it works for me.