# MongoDB wants GeoJSON BoundingBox property of object Feature to be mapped

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-core, coordinates, geojson

I would like to use a ***GeoJSON*** Feature Object to represent the locations in my ***ASP.Net Core Web API***. I have used to following code to insert the sample data to my ***MongoDb Database***:

```
db.Measurements.insertMany([{
        'Degree': 1.3,
        'Location': {
           "type": "Feature",
           "geometry": {
             "type": "Point",
             "coordinates": [49.04852804478914, 9.173037938241464]
           },
           "properties": {
             "name": "Neckar"
           }
         },
        'MeasurementTime': ISODate("2020-03-10T10:50:42.389Z"),
        'MachineId': '6dsfal865kkl34l32'
    }, ...
```

To map this data, I have written the model class below, [following the instructions in Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mongo-app?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio-code#prerequisites).

```
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;
using BAMCIS.GeoJSON;
using System;

public class Measurement
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement]
    public decimal PollutionDegree { get; set; }

    [BsonElement]
    public Feature Location { get; set; }

    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/39331230/776348
    [BsonElement]
    [BsonDateTimeOptions(Kind = DateTimeKind.Local)]
    public DateTime MeasurementTime { get; set; }

    [BsonElement]
    public string MachineId { get; set; }
}
```

**The API works fine without the Location**, but when I uncomment those two lines and add the data in my measurements collection, I get the error message below:

```
    An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in MongoDB.Bson.dll but
was not handled in user code: 'An error occurred while deserializing the Location
 property of class API.Models.Measurement: Member 'BoundingBox' is not mapped.'

     Inner exceptions found, see $exception in variables window for more details.
     Innermost exception     MongoDB.Bson.BsonSerializationException : Member 'BoundingBox' is not mapped.
       at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonCreatorMap.Freeze()
       at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMap.Freeze()
       at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMap.LookupClassMap(Type classType)
       at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMapSerializationProvider.GetSerializer(Type type, IBsonSerializerRegistry serializerRegistry)
       at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializerRegistry.CreateSerializer(Type type)
       at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
       at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializerRegistry.GetSerializer(Type type)
       at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer.LookupSerializer(Type type)
       at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonMemberMap.GetSerializer()
       at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMapSerializer`1.DeserializeMemberValue(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonMemberMap memberMap)
```

Now, what I do not understand with this error message is following:

It says that that an exception thrown because of the absence of the BoundingBox property. But BoundingBox does not seem to be a mandatory property for a Feature Object.

According to RFC696, a bounding box is not one of the [properties that a Feature Object has to possess](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7946#section-3.2). Moreover, a Bounding Box is described as it [MAY be a part of a Feature object](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7946#section-5).

I would appreciate if anyone can explain what needs to be done to read the data properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB only supports a subset of GeoJSON objects.  See [GeoJSON Object](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/geojson/#geojson-objects) in the docs.

It is a short list:

- Point
- LineString
- Polygon
- MultiPoint
- MultiLineString
- MultiPolygon
- GeometryCollection

Comment: Then the error/exception message is somewhat misleading.