# Mongodb complex aggregate query with Datetime field: how to deal with timezones?

Tags: c#, mongodb, timezone

> MongoDB stores all DateTimes in UTC.

A simple way to deal with timezone is the following:

```
[BsonDateTimeOptions(Kind = DateTimeKind.Local)]
public DateTime Date
{ get; set; }
```

Source of the above: [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39318196/mongodb-c-sharp-driver-and-datetime-field/39331230)

Unfortunately I have a complex aggregate query like the following:

```
collection.Aggregate().Match(...).SortByDescending(...).
Group(...).Match(...).
Lookup<...>(...).
Unwind<...>(...).
Project(p => new MyResultClass
  {
   ...
   Date = DateFromAggregate
   }).ToList();
```

It is useless to annotate Date inside **MyResultClass** with **[BsonDateTimeOptions(Kind = DateTimeKind.Local)]**, cannot even do

```
Date = DateFromAggregate.ToLocalTime()
```

inside **Project**, it is not supported, at least in my c# driver version (2.9.2).

I can get the results with the correct timezone executing a loop on all the elements of the list and call **ToLocalTime()**.

Is there another way, possibly using annotations ?

Comment: typically you store everything in the db in UTC format (which is the default) and you also query everything in UTC. finally it is only converted to local time at presentation in the client. storing in localtime is a bad idea because it becomes impossible to handle multiple timezones.