# MongoDB insert is altering date from object to input?

Tags: c#, mongodb, datetime, razor-pages

I have a small problem where an object that I insert into a mongoDB collection has a different DateTime value as soon as it is inserted.

It actually changes exactly -13 hours.

The date from the object to insert is: `{2/16/2022 12:00:00 AM}`

The date from the object in the DB after adding it is: `2022-02-15 23:00:00.000Z`

Am I missing some kind of cast or anything?

This is the insert function:

```
public void Add(string sCollectionName, T tObjectToInsert)
{
        try
        {
            IMongoCollection<T> mcMongoDBCollection = m_dbDatabase.GetCollection<T>(sCollectionName);
            mcMongoDBCollection.InsertOne(tObjectToInsert);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw (new System.Exception("Error during insert in MongoDB. Code: " + e.Message));
        }
}
```

Comment: That's only one hour difference. Mongo is probably expecting UTC time and I guess you are an hour ahead? Is your date actually a DateTime or is it a string?

Comment: woops i confused AM with PM sorry :). And yes its a DateTime. Ill look into the UTC thing.

Comment: You might try changing the DateTime to DateTimeOffset so you can set the timezone offset. I'm not sure if the Mongo provider will pick that up but it's worth a try.

Comment: Does this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39318196/mongodb-c-sharp-driver-and-datetime-field